# save ansi special character in oracle database using php

Tags: php, oracle

Can somebody tell me how can i save **`œ`** which comes from `ALT+0156` i tried to save in database but it is showing **`¿`**

I have looked around but couldn't find any way. Currently i'm using

```
NLS_LANGUAGE =  AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET = 'AL32UTF8'
CHARACTER SET   WE8ISO8859P1
```

Actually i need to save UTF8 data in database but these symbols not coming in right format. Please tell me what i'm missing.

Even i ran a query in [Oracle Sql Developer Tools](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html)

```
select 'œ' val from dual;
```

It returns

```
val => ¿ //as result
```

Comment: Have you specified `UTF-8` as the charset when connecting from PHP to Oracle?  Are you using [OCI8](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) or [PDO_OCI](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.connection.php)?

Comment: @timclutton - Yes.. I have used `oci_connect(DB_NAME, DB_PSWD, HOST, 'AL32UTF8')` and Yes I'm using OCI8.

Comment: `AL32UTF8` is not a valid client-side charset (only server). Use `UTF8` instead.

Comment: @timclutton - I tried that but i'm getting same result.

Comment: Also ensure that all your PHP files are saved in UTF8 and you are correctly setting a response header or meta tag that specifies the charset encoding.

Comment: Yes .. thats all right. I'm doing everything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148589/discussion-between-shail-paras-and-timclutton).

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced similar issues with special characters in Oracle DB.

Your oracle might be compatible with that particular special character but your server/system is not hence you need to add an environmental variable named NLS_LANG.

For Linux/Unix you can simply add it in the .profile/.bash_profile

```
Eg. export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
```

For Windows you can right click your

```
PC -> Goto properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environmental Variables.
```

Path:[Control Panel\System and Security\System -> Advanced system settings -> Environmental Variables. ]

And add a NLS_LANG variable in system variables section.

Note: The value to save in this NLS_LANG environmental variable is returned using below query [In Windows/Linux both]:

```
 select userenv('language') from dual
```

Note that you need to restart your windows system after adding the variable.

Try the following reference link & do the necessary configurations : [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12102_01/books/AnyInstAdm784/AnyInstAdmPreInstall18.html) and it should hopefully work out.

Comment: This is a link-only answer and, while the link may answer the question, it would be better to include the salient points in your answer.

Comment: Hello @MT0 , Thanks for the tip. Will keep in mind for future purposes however I am not sure what else I can add in this particular answer.

Comment: hi @pOrinG - i tried to check the NLS_LANG and i found it's fine in there. I run this query `SELECT USERENV ('language') FROM DUAL;` and it gives me `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1`. So My Question is Are you asking me to change `AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1` to `AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8`

Comment: @Shail Paras Let me edit my answer so you understand my proposed solution better.

Comment: @ShailParas Please note that I am not asking you to change any oracle db parameters/variables.

Comment: @pOrinG - I'm not working in localhost (windows).. its Linux based live stage server. Where i'm using php to connect oracle database.

Comment: @ShailParas You need to add this variable in all the systems from which you are connecting the DB. You can add it in the linux box as well using export command as indicated above.

Comment: can i do this by setting some environment variables? Like `putenv('NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8')`

Comment: @ShailParas Yes you can from my understanding, just make sure your putting the correct value returned by [ select userenv('language') from dual] query. I personally always prefer to use export NLS_LANG=[value]. Once you exported just use sqlplus and try the simple query to return the special char from dual.