# putenv not making any effect - oracle database

Tags: php, oracle

I am trying to change `NLS_LANG` in `OracleDatabase` using `putenv`.
It works fine when i do this:

```
$a = putenv("NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8");
var_dump($a); // bool(true)
$ab = getenv("NLS_LANG");
var_dump($ab); // string(25) "AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8"
```

But when I connect and query the same it gives me different result:

```
$dbSetting = '(DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
    (HOST = SERVER_HOST)(PORT = 15210)) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = orcl) 
    (SID = orcl)))';
$conn = oci_connect('dbuser', 'dbuser', $dbSetting, 'AL32UTF8') or die('db not connected');
$stid = oci_parse($conn, "select userenv('language') from dual");
     oci_execute($stid);

while($row = oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC)){
   $arr[] = $row;
}
var_dump($arr);
```

I got this result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["USERENV('LANGUAGE')"]=>
    string(29) "AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1"
  }
}
```

Why??

Please help me to find what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about first setting an environment variable and then checking its value against a database parameter, which goes by the same name ?

Comment: Yes i'm talking about the same..First set/get using putenv and getenv then query for the same..

Comment: **SELECT USERENV ('language') FROM DUAL; gives the session's <Language>_<territory> but the DATABASE character set not the client, so the value returned is not the client's complete NLS_LANG setting!**. Check this link here-> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html

Comment: Ok. I understood now whats happening. thanks for your comment. But can i ask u one thing  - if i change the value of env variable then why it is not working?That means changed value is not affecting in client session.Then what is benefit of setting env variables?

Comment: Check again my last comment: SELECT USERENV ('language') FROM DUAL; gives **the session's <Language>_<territory>**. That is valid for your current session. That is why you can select it in the same session and it will return the same result. Selecting it from another session will just return that particular session's env. variable and NOT the one you set for your session. Does it look clear now? Let me know. If that solves it, I guess I can write an answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks @g00dy for making this clear to me. I'm doing this for my earlier 
 asked question - [Saving Special Character in Oracle Db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948626/save-ansi-special-character-in-oracle-database-using-php/44948817)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that following the comments below the question I can write the answer here:

> **SELECT USERENV ('language') FROM DUAL; gives the session's**
>   **Language and Territory** but the DATABASE character set not the client,
>   so the value returned is not the client's complete NLS_LANG setting.
>   [[LINK]](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/globalization/nls-lang-099431.html).

As to why "if one changes the value of env. variable then it's not visible" - check the bold part of my answer above.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Because Oracle libraries can be loaded, or connections created, before your code runs, you should never set Oracle environment variables in code because the outcome is not deterministic.